# Using scikit-learn to train on multidimensional data

Tags: python, scikit-learn

It's a very basic concept: I have more than one dependency for training. My data is all text and I have three separate fields. Every example I have been able to find has text data set up like this:

```
data = ['text1','text2',...]
```

where mine looks like:

```
data = [['text1','text2','text3'],[...],...]
```

but when I try and fit to the data I get the following traceback:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-e3356a0f62f8> in <module>()
----> 1 classifier.fit(X,y)

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.pyc in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    140                              "by not using the ``sparse`` parameter")
    141 
--> 142         X = atleast2d_or_csr(X, dtype=np.float64, order='C')
    143 
    144         if self.impl in ['c_svc', 'nu_svc']:

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.pyc in atleast2d_or_csr(X, dtype, order, copy)
    114     """
    115     return _atleast2d_or_sparse(X, dtype, order, copy, sparse.csr_matrix,
--> 116                                 "tocsr")
    117 
    118 

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.pyc in _atleast2d_or_sparse(X, dtype, order, copy, sparse_class, convmethod)
     94         _assert_all_finite(X.data)
     95     else:
---> 96         X = array2d(X, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
     97         _assert_all_finite(X)
     98     return X

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.pyc in array2d(X, dtype, order, copy)
     78         raise TypeError('A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data '
     79                         'is required. Use X.toarray() to convert to dense.')
---> 80     X_2d = np.asarray(np.atleast_2d(X), dtype=dtype, order=order)
     81     _assert_all_finite(X_2d)
     82     if X is X_2d and copy:

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.pyc in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    318 
    319     """
--> 320     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    321 
    322 def asanyarray(a, dtype=None, order=None):

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

is there a specific way I have to approach this? Thank you!

NOTES:

All of the text data I am using is vectorized by a `HashingVectorizer`

`clf.fit(X,y)` where `X` is a list of lists that contain 3 vectorized texts, and `y` is a list of the respective categories that the element of `X` belongs to

Comment: Please clarify your question. What is your model, or in other words, what are your trying to classify? What exactly are you fitting to classifier.fit(X,y)? X has to be a numeric array, and y - array of class labels. If your data is text, than you need to convert it to numeric data, e.g. by counting word frequencies. Please add more details, or show some code, otherwise it's hard to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I made a quick node, it is vectorized using a `HashVectorizer`

Comment: and I am classifying to categories. So in essence, every item has labels, a title, and a description. and I want to classify by a list of specific categories.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

X has to be a 2 dimensional array (or list of lists, if you want). And each list in this list of lists has to be a list of numeric values. And all this lists must have the same length. Like this: [[1,2,3,5],[3,4,5,6],[6,7,8,9],...]. If for each object you have several text entries which you are vectorizing, you need to combine the resultant vectorized texts into a single list. For example, concatenating them, if it makes sense in your context. So eventually each object has to be represented by a single list where all entries are numeric. And all objects must be represented by lists of equal length, where corresponding elements in all the lists represent the same feature (e.g. frequency of the same token in your texts). Let me know whether what I'm saying makes sense.

Comment: That makes sense, but I cannot concatenate the data, they are 3 very separate fields (description, title, tags)

Comment: Well, this is how standard classification algorithms work. They require a set of numeric features for each object. And you need to design your features so that they will fit this model. So that you data could be represented by a 2 dimensional matrix, where each row is an object, and each column is a numeric feature.

Comment: And this is still an open research topic on how to encode relationships between features, e.g. if you have groups of features, or a hierarchy of features. I saw some research papers on this matter, but I'm not aware of amy implementations in standard machine learning libraries.

Comment: Text mining is a complex problem, there's no magic solution that would solve your problem. This takes some time and research. I would say, start with this simple concatenation that I suggested. See how it works. It still could perform reasonably. Then, try to do some research and find some other strategies for your problem. I have not work on text mining, so I do not have any good references on top of my head.