# Kmeans Clustering with n-dimensional arrays in Sklearn python

Tags: python, arrays, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have an array in Python composed by several different arrays with different dimensions, for instance:

```
 KB=[[[1,2],[2,4],[2,4,5,3],[5,4,3,2,1]],[[1,2],[2,4],[2,4,5,3],
      [5,4,3,2,1]],........]
```

Basically, each entry in that array has a fixed number of sub arrays which could be characterized by different dimensions (the first entry has 2-D, the third entry has 4-D and so on).

Now, using `sklearn` in python with kmeans I obtained an error like this:

```
  array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
  ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

This due to the different dimensions about the entries within the main array.

How can I compute clusters for a given input containing sub-arrays with different dimensions?

Comment: According to the following url, it is not possible.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961233/using-scikit-learn-to-train-on-multidimensional-data

Comment: You should post your whole code and full stack trace of error.

Comment: Why don't you normalize the dimensions of each sub array to, let's say be the same length as the longer by padding them?

Answer (score 0):

K-means requires computing *means*.

What would be the mean vector of

```
[1,2]
[3,4,5,6]
```

In order to compute centroids, k-means *requires* a d-dimensional vector field.